# PHP | Get value in array | WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array. How do I pull the post date value out of it? Like "Test Title"

```
Array
(
    [product_id] =&gt; 50559
    [variation_id] =&gt; 
    [quantity] =&gt; 1
    [data] =&gt; WC_Product_Simple Object
        (
            [id] =&gt; 50559
            [post] =&gt; WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] =&gt; 50559
                    [post_author] =&gt; 1
                    [post_date] =&gt; 2015-05-25 20:30:21
                    [post_title] =&gt; Test Title
```

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. How i can give to you "+"?

Comment: Posted my answer. But you should also post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`print_r($your_array_name['data']->post->post_title);`